# carouFredSel jQuery in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I am using carouFredSel jQuery as a slider on this html code:

```
<div class="list_carousel">
        <ul id="foo">
            <li>c</li>
            <li>a</li>
            <li>r</li>
            <li>o</li>
            <li>u</li>
            <li>F</li>
            <li>r</li>
            <li>e</li>
            <li>d</li>
            <li>S</li>
            <li>e</li>
            <li>l</li>
            <li> </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <a id="prev" class="prev" href="#">&lt;</a>
        <a id="next" class="next" href="#">&gt;</a>
        <div id="pager2" class="pager"></div>
    </div>
```

and the jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.0.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#foo').carouFredSel({
                    auto: false,
                    prev: '#prev',
                    next: '#next',
                    pagination: "#pager",
                    mousewheel: true,
                    swipe: {
                        onMouse: true,
                        onTouch: true
                    }
                });
});
</script>
```

When I use it in standard html, it works fine but when I transfer the code to a WordPress site, the query just doesn't work. What might be wrong?

Comment: do you load the jQuery as above in Wordpress? if so, you need to put it in [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) mode

Answer (score 0):

Surely might be a Script source mistake.. Look after the path which You refered while pasting in that website....

Comment: You were loading jQuery twice and you were loading the carusel in the wrong place i think http://jsfiddle.net/s39Kd/4/

Comment: What do you mean by loading carousal in wrong place? I tried the code you demonstrated but still no hope.. Cam you plz give me a little further explanation?

Comment: Here is the code as I use it in HTML. working perfectly http://jsfiddle.net/7amama/rz5Fy/

Answer (score 0):

add in the wordpress header and footer. that worked for me. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've resolved this or not but hexblot is right, switch up the '$' with 'jQuery' to avoid conflict.